# How to insert a single point feature into a shapefile?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

I have the following problem. I am doing an analysis which creates a shapefile **"A"** with one or more point features. In the next step I need to insert the individual point features of the shapefile **"A"** into another point shapefile **"B"** which stores the results from multiple analyses. How do I insert (append) features from **"A"** into **"B"**? Both shapefiles have the same attributes (shapefile "B" has one additional attribute) and I need to transfer them as well.

Here is the code I think should work but it does not:

```
analysis_res = fcn1(inp1, inp2) # analysis results - shapefile "A"
cursorA = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(analysis_res)
cursorB = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outFile, ['SHAPE@'])
for row in cursorA:
     cursorB.inserRow(row) # here I would like to insert the poit feature of "A" into "B"
del cursorA, cursorB
```

Comment: The shapefile schemas as not "the same" if one has more fields than the other.

Comment: They are the same except of the second one having an additional field. I wanted to emphasize that the rest of the fields are the same.

Comment: So they're the same except where they're different, but the *difference* is the part that creates the problem. uour Python doesn't work for many reasons, but not explicitly listing which columns is one of them.

Comment: @Vince is right. You need to specify which fields are part of your SearchCursor.
`cursorA = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(analysis_res, ['SHAPE@'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [append](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm) tool with schema test disabled.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways how to do it is this one:

```
#result of the analysis
shpA = fcn1(inp1, inp2)

# get field names
fieldObj = arcpy.ListFields(shpA)
fieldList = []
for fld in fieldObj:
    fieldList.append(fld.name)
fields = tuple(list(fieldList[2:]) + list(["SHAPE@XY"]))

# create cursor objects
cursorA = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shpA, fields)
cursorB = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(shpB, fields)

# insert rows
for row in cursorA:
    cursorB.inserRow(row)

# delete cursors
del cursorA, cursorB
```

Comment: It's better practice to use the `with` construct when possible (on the search cursor)